# Accessing multiple cloned fields from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form which has the ability to copy a row of several fields using jquery - my question is how do I access these form values in the target php page?

Answer (score 3):

If they have the same 'name' attribute value, change that value to 'name[]' so that they look like

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
//etc...
```

and you should be able to access them by using:

```
$value = $_POST['name'][0];
```

where 0 is the index of the field, IE, the first field is 0, second is 1...

It is easier to access these using a for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']; $i++)
    // actions with $_POST['name'][$i]
```

or a foreach loop.

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $value)
    // actions with $value
```

Comment: Thankyou - this is how I would access one cloned field - but how would I access the values from the clones of several fields?

Comment: Do the same thing, except for each cloned field "set" use a different identifier, such as "fieldset1[]" "fieldset2[]", etc, where each field set hold one "type" of cloned field. Then access these names using loops as needed.

Comment: The values of each field will be added to a mysql table - do you know how I would formulate the query string when using multiple foreach loops? - I realise this may be a stupid question but I am just getting back into php after focusing on graphic design for several years.

Comment: It depends on how you have your database set up and how you want that data entered.

Answer (score 3):

Any code, by chance? Anyway, you can make it add a name to the new field with square braces, so ti will be accessed as an array, like it happens with multiselect checkboxes

```
es: new field 1 <input type="text" name="added[]" value="">
    new field 2 <input type="text" name="added[]" value="">
```

and so on...

Then you have everythin in the $_POST['added'] array

Comment: If I have another cloned form element called "anotheradded" could I use a foreach statement to access both arrays?

Comment: You would have to use a for each for both the added[] array and the anotheradded[] array. You couldn't do both at once.

Comment: The values of each field will be added to a mysql table - do you know how I would formulate the query string when using multiple foreach loops? - I realise this may be a stupid question but I am just getting back into php after focusing on graphic design for several years.

Comment: Sorry Damien - still getting into this sites format - I thought I had thanked you below but that was another user! (Thankyou by the way!)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how jquery is adding them. Do the following on the called page and see how they're being passed through.

```
var_dump( $_POST ); // Or maybe $_GET
```

Comment: will have to try this at the office tomorrow (site is on a local server for development) - thankyou for your help so far!